# Burning of Resistor in the Clamp Circuit of an SMPS

Tags: resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, clamp

This circuit has been designed and optimised. When implementing on PCB R3 resistor is burning up. Any reasons or suggestions for this to happen? Circuit is stable and safe when supplied with 190V and any higher R3 starts burning up.

[image: Power Supply for 150W]

Comment: What power rating the R3 has?

Comment: I went with the PI design and it has power rating of 0.125W

Comment: Try a 1W rated part. If it goes up in smoke, then I’d suggest looking at the snubber circuit to ensure that is correctly implemented then the transformer construction.

Comment: You should measure the voltage across \$R_1\$, the clamp resistor with a dc volt-meter and see how far it is from the 130-V TVS. If too close, especially when you increase the input voltage, this could be the issue as the hard clamp induces high power dissipated in the TVS. How many volts are you supposedly reflecting on the primary side at turn off?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, there was some issue with R9 and R11 have changed them and the output voltage is fine, but the efficiency is too low, only 50%